# Pause a macro then work on a sheet, then resume macro

Tags: excel, excel-2007, vba

How can I pause a macro work on a sheet creating several graphs, study them, study various cells and then resume the macro?

I have tried using `MsgBox` which pauses the macro but will not let me work on the sheet. I have done numerous Google searches to no avail.

Comment: How about splitting the macro into two or more? For e.g. pre-verification macro and post-verification macro? Assign a shortcut to both of these and then press that key at each stage.

Comment: thanks ; gosh i don't understand how to this; can explain more?

Comment: gosh i don't understand how to this; can explain more?

Comment: Pull the code from the point where you use `MsgBox` into another `public sub` (say macro2) and put that into a bas module. Assign a shortcut key using the macros dialog box to it. Press the key when you are done verifying, which will run the new macro2.

Comment: You can insert a button which on a click will call the `Stop()` method or you may place the stop() method where ever you want the code to wait.

Comment: thanks is there a way you can email and example of how to do this?

Comment: thanks is there way you can email and example of how to do this;

Comment: @user2826486 `Sub A()
    Call B
    Stop
    MsgBox "test"
End Sub

Sub B()
    Application.Wait Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 5)
End Sub`  Here is sample code.

Comment: @pnuts Infact i had also missed it. :)

Comment: @pnuts Alright. Cheers

Comment: i put in a stop command in my macro; it allows me stop the macro at the desired point and create a grap and work;

Comment: put in a stop command in my macro; it allows me stop the macro at the desired point and create a graph and work how do continue the macro running;

Answer (score 2):

Here is a typical mechanism:

```
Sub TwoParts()
    '     do the first part
    MsgBox "Enter a value in A1 when done"
    While [A1] = ""
        DoEvents
    Wend
    MsgBox "Proceeding with second part actions"
    '     do other stuff
End Sub
```

We:

- do some stuff
- tell the User to do his stuff
- wait until user fills A1
- do the second part

Comment: thanks but i have found i can get what i want by placing a stop command in macro; it does stop and allow me work on sheet creating graphs and check cell values etc; but i cannot figure out how to continue macro when i am finished l i tried cntG so how can i continue the macro? thanks

Comment: My solution is very easy.  If you find an easier solution, please post it!

Comment: gary using the Msgbox does not work; becuase when using it i cannot work on the sheet, i.e. creating graphs, examining cells etc;

Comment: hanks but i have found i can get what i want by placing a stop command in macro; it does stop and allow me work on sheet creating graphs and check cell values etc; but i cannot figure out how to continue macro when i am finished l i tried cntG so how can i continue the macro? thanks – user2826486 1 hour ago

Comment: This is a little messy running a loop continually till a value is entered. A basic UserForm would be a tidier approach.

Comment: I know this is old but after I click the message box for "enter something in A1 when done", Excel doesn't allow me to edit any cells. It just locks up.

Comment: @Gary'sStudent Yes I guess I did, I am trying to paste charts into PowerPoint after the user is done editing certain cells (which change the Chart)

Comment: Can I just add a application.enableevents = false and application.enableevents = true before and after ?